# Automotive engine compartment parts and connection diagram

Tags: engine, part-identification, automotive-design

Is there is a site that can show me the complete engine compartment part locations and connections? I need a site that can show me the same that the auto parts store have, that once you input the car make and model, it will pop up and you can just click on the part and it will give me the part number and all the details.

I need it because some times you do not know the name of the part but you know the location of it in the car, and also it will help me a lot in understand the car and what it has.

Does this exist? Instead of searching on the internet by name of the part or the part number, I need drawings.

Note:
My car is a 2011 Silverado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be different for each car, but the best options for seeing connections and names of parts is getting a shop manual. This will have many diagrams and exploded images of the car you need to work on. Many of these exploded images will have a numbered list telling you which part is what similar to the below image

[image: engine diagram]

There are also online shop manuals such as mitchell and all data. sometimes parts store websites like autozone have pretty good list of manual pages. You can also see if the dealer will give you a copy of their shop manual or you may be able to download it online.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I want. from where i can get one like these ?

Comment: you can see if you can find one floating around the internet for your car sometimes someone has posted one for download else you can purchase one either online or at a parts store. you can also go to the dealer and see if they will get you a shop manual. you can also use generic terms in google image search for things like "ignition system" with your vehicles make, model, and year

Comment: I will do. but are there any websites can provide these information for free ? or for a cheap subscriptions ? how the autoparts stores have thousands of database for almost all the cars ? there should be a site for that

Comment: well the issue with auto pats stores is they have databases that are based off key words such as water pump and that gets matched with your make model year and engine. Yes there is usually a bunch of online resources and the best thing to do is search google images for what you are looking for such as make model engine year "xyz diagram" or "shop manual" and see what comes up. lastly many public libraries will order shop manuals on request.